# JUnit ServiceTest for delete method which tells me Wanted but not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am stuck at a delete test now.

Here is the delete method of PostServiceImpl.class

```
@Override
public void deletePostById(Long id) {
    Post post = postRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("post", "id", id));

    postRepository.delete(post);
}
```

PostServiceTest.class

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    postDto = new PostDto();
    postDto.setId(1L);
    postDto.setTitle("test title");
    postDto.setDescription("test description");
    postDto.setContent("test content");

    post = new Post();
    post.setId(1L);
    post.setTitle("test title");
    post.setDescription("test description");
    post.setContent("test content");
}

@Test
void givenPostId_whenDeletePost_thenNothing() {

    Long postId = 1L;

    BDDMockito.given(postRepository.findById(postId))
            .willReturn(Optional.of(post));

    BDDMockito.willDoNothing().given(postRepository).deleteById(postId);

    postService.deletePostById(postId);

    Mockito.verify(postRepository, Mockito.times(1)).findById(1L);
    Mockito.verify(postRepository, Mockito.times(1)).deleteById(1L);
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
postRepository.deleteById(1L);
-> at com.springboot.blog.service.PostServiceTest.givenPostId_whenDeletePost_thenNothing(PostServiceTest.java:148)

However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:
postRepository.findById(1L);
-> at com.springboot.blog.service.PostServiceImpl.deletePostById(PostServiceImpl.java:95)

postRepository.delete(
Post(id=1, title=test title, description=test description, content=test content, createdTime=null, updatedTime=null));
-> at com.springboot.blog.service.PostServiceImpl.deletePostById(PostServiceImpl.java:98)
```

I do not really know what mistakes I made and any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking whether

```
postRespository.deleteById(1l);
```

is being called once here

```
Mockito.verify(postRepository, Mockito.times(1)).deleteById(1L);
```

But your PostServiceImpl.class is not calling that method. It is calling the

```
postRepository.delete(post);
```

which takes the Post class as parameter. Change the verification statement to

```
Mockito.verify(postRepository, Mockito.times(1)).delete(post);
```

and it should work.

Comment: Ranjit C Thanks!! I am careless and thank you for your help!! Test case code works when I edited like below:

    @Test
    void givenPostId_whenDeletePost_thenNothing() {

        Long postId = 1L;

        BDDMockito.given(postRepository.findById(postId))
                .willReturn(Optional.of(post));

        BDDMockito.willDoNothing().given(postRepository).delete(post);

        
postService.deletePostById(postId);

        Mockito.verify(postRepository, Mockito.times(1)).findById(1L);
        Mockito.verify(postRepository, Mockito.times(1)).delete(post);
    }